# Verify the integrity of a file downloaded from Apache

Tags: apache, hash, public-key, pgp, integrity

I followed instruction on this page to verify the integrity of the download file. The file is a Sqoop installation, but my question is not specific to Sqoop.
http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/sqoop/1.4.7

At the backup site page I downloaded two files - asc file and md5 file.
https://www-eu.apache.org/dist/sqoop/1.4.7/

The instruction said I need to download KEYS file, PGP signature file (asc file), or PGP hash file (md5). So I think for this particular download there is no KEYS file?

I used the following command in CentOS, verifying the file with hash.

gpg --print-md MD5 sqoop-1.4.7.bin__hadoop-2.6.0.tar.gz

I got the hash value, which matches to the downloaded md5 file by characters, but NOT by case. 
So **question #1**: Is PGP Hash verification case-insensitive?

In addition, **Question #2**: because there is no KEYS file to download, how do I use the asc file to verify file integrity? I tried the command on the instruction page but none of them worked for me.

Comment: Case is not relevant in the MD5 hash. That is, 'f' is the same as 'F'.

Comment: @JimMischel, Thanks for the confirmation.